# Application dies with "Low Memory: No more background processes."

Tags: android

In my application i try launching the browser with the following url:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=indiranagar bangalore&daddr=mgroad bangalore
```

The browser launches and when the map loads my application gets killed with the following logcat message:

```
    I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=
http://View cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 355

I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=indiranagar bangalore&daddr=mgroad bangalore
cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 355
D/PhoneWindow(  355): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused vie
w android.widget.EditText@40587640 has no id.
I/ActivityManager(   61): Displayed com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity: +760ms

W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  355): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
I/dalvikvm(  373): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
I/System.out(  355): Logout Counter:30
D/dalvikvm(  373): GC_CONCURRENT freed 369K, 50% free 3921K/7751K, external 2234
K/2645K, paused 5ms+18ms
D/dalvikvm(  355): GC_EXPLICIT freed 866K, 50% free 3666K/7239K, external 2693K/
3310K, paused 1640ms
D/dalvikvm(  373): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1400K, 54% free 3641K/7751K, external 226
6K/2645K, paused 6ms+26ms
W/browser (  373): We should not show context menu when nothing is touched
W/browser (  373): We should not show context menu when nothing is touched
W/browser (  373): We should not show context menu when nothing is touched
**I/ActivityManager(   61): Process com.aavarp.mobile (pid 355) has died.
I/ActivityManager(   61): Low Memory: No more background processes.**
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{408793c0 com.aavarp.mobile/com.aavarp.
mobile.core.ui.ApplicationsActivity paused=false}
E/InputDispatcher(   61): channel '4070e4f8 com.aavarp.mobile/com.aavarp.mobile.
dashboard.ui.components.GraphActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel
or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(   61): channel '4070e4f8 com.aavarp.mobile/com.aavarp.mobile.
dashboard.ui.components.GraphActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broke
n and will be disposed!
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{4070e4f8 com.aavarp.mobile/com.aavarp.
mobile.dashboard.ui.components.GraphActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{406836a8 com.aavarp.mobile/com.aavarp.
mobile.dashboard.ui.components.NotificationList paused=false}
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{406825a8 com.aavarp.mobile/com.aavarp.
mobile.dashboard.ui.components.TableListActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{4083df30 com.aavarp.mobile/com.aavarp.
mobile.dashboard.ui.components.DetailsActivity paused=false}
E/InputDispatcher(   61): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input c
hannel.  fd=171, events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(   61): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input c
hannel.  fd=175, events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(   61): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input c
hannel.  fd=181, events=0x8
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1735K, 52% free 4435K/9159K, external 529
2K/6609K, paused 8ms+16ms
D/skia    (  129): purging 38K from font cache [5 entries]
D/dalvikvm(  129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 84K, 52% free 2801K/5767K, external 2117K/2
643K, paused 73ms
```

Again i tried launching the browser from my application with `www.google.com` and performed a search and browsed through various pages and navigated back to my application without any issues. I am not sure if am missing some message on the logcat. I use Android 2.3 OS.Could someone kindly help me resolve this issue please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about sharing some code as the logcat doesn't point to anything obvious.

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to load the maps in webview..? you load the map in a [**map activity**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) or

use [Intents List: Invoking Google Applications on Android Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

```
   String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + "9982878"+","+"76285774"+"&daddr="+"9992084"+","+"76286455";
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Note: for displaying [route](http://bit.ly/P5UlCL) you should use map activity canvas

Comment: for map activity yes..  right click on the project change it to google api and get the  [keystore](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)